# Google Script to authorize account to do specific action

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script

I just create a menu in my spreadsheet and I want to add a list of user who could use this menu. I just wonder whether I could use some methods like addEditors(emailAddress) or some others methods to achieve this? Here is the code I write

```
function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Add new row', 'addNewRow') 
      .addItem('Delete last row', 'deleteLastRow')
      .addToUi();
}
```

currently I want to grant some user like "me@gst.org.us" and "you@gst.org.us" to use this methods, others cannot.

Could I please ask how could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Scripts bounded to spreadsheets, documents, forms and slides inherits the access controls from the files they are bounded to. This means that you could edit edit who can ran the script by limiting who has edit access to the file.

Reference

[Container-bound Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)